# android load image from url not same load image from file

Tags: android

i follow [this link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-loading-image-from-url-http/) to load image from url

this is activity

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewImg3"/>

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

this is Binderdata if load image from file

```
public class trang3Binderdata extends BaseAdapter {
static final String KEY_IMG = "img";
LayoutInflater inflater;
List<HashMap<String,String>> imgHashmap;
ViewHolder holder;
public trang3Binderdata() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public trang3Binderdata(Activity act, List<HashMap<String,String>> map) {
    this.imgHashmap = map;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) act
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    return imgHashmap.size();
}

public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null){
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_img, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.ivImgtrang3 =(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imageViewImg3);
        vi.setTag(holder);
    }
    else{

        holder = (ViewHolder)vi.getTag();
    }

    String uri = "drawable/"+ imgHashmap .get(position).get(KEY_IMG);
    int imageResource = vi.getContext().getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, vi.getContext().getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
    Drawable image = vi.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
    holder.ivImgtrang3.setImageDrawable(image);

    return vi;
}

static class ViewHolder{
    ImageView ivImgtrang3;
}
```

}

this is result
[image]

this is Binderdata load image from url

```
public class trang3Binderdata extends BaseAdapter {
static final String KEY_IMG = "img";
LayoutInflater inflater;
List<HashMap<String,String>> imgHashmap;
ViewHolder holder;
public trang3Binderdata() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public trang3Binderdata(Activity act, List<HashMap<String,String>> map) {
    this.imgHashmap = map;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) act
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return imgHashmap.size();
}

public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null){
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_img, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.ivImgtrang3 =(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imageViewImg3);
        vi.setTag(holder);
    }
    else{

        holder = (ViewHolder)vi.getTag();
    }

    int loader = R.drawable.skorea;
    String uri = imgHashmap .get(position).get(KEY_IMG);
    ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(vi.getContext().getApplicationContext());
    imgLoader.DisplayImage(uri, loader, holder.ivImgtrang3);

    return vi;
}

static class ViewHolder{
    ImageView ivImgtrang3;
}
```

}

this is result
[image]

I want load image from url like load image from file. but result not same size.why that?
please help me. thank you for reading

Comment: Yes. Size of image when load from url not same when load from file. Can you fix it?

Comment: provide your xml file ? that include R.id.imageViewImg3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change your layout xml to match your needs , I remove RelativeLayout cause I see its not necessary as you you have only one image view .you may need set scaleType in your image to reach best scale view

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent" // change width to match parent 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  // change height to specific number or let it as its wrap_content
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewImg3"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i follow you, but image in central and size not change . it still small

Comment: if change android:layout_height="number dp" size of image will large. but I want it auto. can you have any idea ?

Comment: try change your LinearLayout width to match_parent , and height to any number you want let say 100dp-150dp will be nice dont forget add scaletype , android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:scaleType="centerCrop"

Comment: is it work or not ? any way you facing issue in image size in xml you can size it as you want with specific number , or by setting width , height wrap content or match parent

Comment: it not like when load image from file. I try any thing you show me. I don't know why. may be I try another tutorial to load image from url

Comment: may be this also help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15741947/android-universal-image-loader-resize-picture-before-displaing-it-in-a-view