# Android load different bitmaps in different size in different activities

Tags: android, bitmap, size, out-of-memory, scaling

Good morning everybody,

I have a big problem with my Android app regarding to memory usage. My app offers (at the moment) 22 card games. Each game is an activity with own specific layout. They are in res/layout folder and all contained views have width and height = 0dp. After loading a layout I calculate the max possible size of cards (view), according to screen size, preferred deck-type (7 types are available) and layout itself and I set the calculated size to each displayed cards (in the worst case there are 52 cards displayed at the same time). Card images (about 100kb for single image) are all in asset folder (assets/${deck_type}/a1.png ...assets/${deck_type}/a52.png).
So, each game has its layout with its specific card-size (known just at runtime). Now my problem is that after playing about 6/7 different games, I encounter an OutOfMemory while loading bitmaps or while loading a new game layout. If you change the deck-type, the OOM arrives about 3/4 games.
Initially I loaded all card images of preferred deck-type in a LruCache (and reload it only after user deck-type changing), and call

```
cardView.setImageDrawable(cardImages.get(card));
```

when cardView is displayed. But with this solution OOM arrives almost soon.
So I have kept this approach but using Bitmap (instead of Drawable), loaded with com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader: little bit better but not well yet. So I've stopped to use a fully preloaded LruCache and sync load bitmap at needing, scaling them according to game-card-size

```
private void scaleImage(int newWidth) {
    int width = scaled.getWidth();
    int height = scaled.getHeight();

    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
    float ratio = ((float) scaled.getWidth()) / newWidth;
    int newHeight = (int) (height / ratio);
    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

    System.gc();
    scaled = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaled, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);

}
```

and cache them in a LruCache, evicted at the end of game and in OnDestroy of my activity game I call

```
System.gc()
```

but seems has no effects.

More little bit better but OOM is not avoided.
I have also studied all five chapters https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

but I wasn't able to adapt them for my need.

How can I solve this problem? Do you know an alternative approach?
Thank you very very much.

Comment: Use any third party libraries like Picasso,Glide,UniversalImageLoader etc.These libraries will do all the memory handling..

Comment: As I wrote, I used UniversalImageLoader but OOM wasn't avoided in my case.

Comment: Did you tried re-sizing the images using ImageLoader.

Comment: Yes but perhaps in a wrong way. Can you suggest me a complete example that fits my case?

Comment: Did you tried like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/25802692/3111083 ?